# Python can't insert multiple rows at once into a MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am learning to use the MySQL Connector/Python. When I insert multiple rows together into the table using the code below, it shows an error. But it works when I insert only one row at at time.

Here's the python code I have written:

```py
import mysql.connector as sql

mydb = sql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "your_password", database = "testdb")

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

str = "insert into test (Name, Address) values (%s, %s)"
val = [
    ('Foster', 'Moonland'),
    ('Toblerone', 'Marstown'),
    ('Hershey', 'Neptunestadt'),
    ('Cadbury', 'Jupiter DC')
]

mycursor.execute(str, val)
mydb.commit()
```

This the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shoun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 183, in to_mysql
    return getattr(self, "_{0}_to_mysql".format(type_name))(value)
AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shoun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 432, in _process_params
    res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
  File "C:\Users\shoun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 432, in <listcomp>
    res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
  File "C:\Users\shoun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 186, in to_mysql
    "MySQL type".format(type_name))
TypeError: Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\coding\python\mysql_connector\connectSQL.py", line 24, in <module>
    mycursor.execute(str, val)
  File "C:\Users\shoun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 557, in execute
    psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))
  File "C:\Users\shoun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 437, in _process_params
    "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

But if `val` is a single tuple, the code executes without producing any error.

Comment: You want to use `mycursor.executemany(stmt, vals)`

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks. That solved the problem.